# Ckeditor image center alignment option

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

Does anyone know how to include a center alignment option for images in ckeditor?

The image below shows what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible using the 'new' image plugin "[Enhanced Image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2)" which relies on the powerful [widget](http://ckeditor.com/addon/widget) plugin, introducing the Widget API and its capability of handling 'templates' within CKEditor.

PS: See also [this](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/How-can-I-center-images) discussion about centering images with CKEditor. And [here](http://ckeditor.com/builder) you can customize your CKEditor build with different plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

The standard ckeditor alignment just adds a CSS float left or right, there is no float:center in css. You could add the plugin to ckeditor and that will give you more options.

A plugin is being worked on for this at the moment. You could download the beta and give it a shot. It goes in the

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10659

You'll need to install the plugin and add some javascript to make it work. There's another post here that shows the process for the justify plugin:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782152/inline-ckeditor-toolbar-has-no-alignment-buttons-for-h2-elements/14810988#14810988